# Loop through all IDs that begin with XXX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would anyone know how to loop through all ID's that being with name_

So, for example, within the markup I may have 50 id's that all start with "name_", the full ID would be like name_2, name_55, name_25, etc.

I'd like to loop through all of these getting the number.

Not really sure where to begin....... thank you!

Comment: maybe you should assign all these elements a common class. does not have to do anything CSS-wise, just for logical grouping in your script.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('[id^=name_]').each(function() {
    var number = this.id.split('_').pop();
});
```