# jQuery shortest way of writing an if argument for adding and removing css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What could be the shortest way of writing the following code?

Before you look at the code, let me break it through. I have 11 `div` with id such as `myManyDiv0`, `myManyDiv1` ... `myManyDiv10`. I also have 2 `div` with id `divSome` and `divMany`.

If `whatever` is `0`, `myManyDiv0` will have the class `visible` and all other `myMany..` div will have the class `visible` removed. Same way, if `whatever` is `1`, `myManyDiv1` will have the class `visible` and all other `myMany..` div will have the class `visible` removed... you get the idea.

But for my other 2 divs `divSome` and `divMamy`, they are quite a bit different.

- If `whatever` is either `0` or `1`, `divSome` will have the class `displayNone` added to them and for `divMany`, `displayNone` removed from it.
- If `whatever` is `2`, `divSome` will have the class `displayNone` removed from it and for `divMany`, `displayNone` added to it.

I guess, I'm pretty bad at explaining it, but I hope you get the idea. Thanks in advance for your lesson.

```
if (whatever == "0") {
    $('#myManyDiv0').addClass('visible'); // visible div
    $('#myManyDiv1').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv2').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv3').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv4').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv5').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv6').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv7').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv8').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv9').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv10').removeClass('visible');
    $('#divSome').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone'); //visible div
} else if (whatever == "1") {
    $('#myManyDiv0').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv1').addClass('visible'); //visible div
    $('#myManyDiv2').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv3').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv4').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv5').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv6').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv7').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv8').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv9').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv10').removeClass('visible');
    $('#divSome').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone'); //visible div
} else if (whatever == "2") {
    $('#myManyDiv0').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv1').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv2').addClass('visible'); //visible div
    $('#myManyDiv3').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv4').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv5').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv6').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv7').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv8').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv9').removeClass('visible');
    $('#myManyDiv10').removeClass('visible');
    $('#divSome').removeClass('displayNone'); //visible div
    $('#divMany').addClass('displayNone');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to avoid the repetition of all those "myManyDiv" you could just loop through them all. You can select all divs that start with myManyDiv like so:

```
$('[id^=myManyDiv]')
```

(credit to: [Loop through all IDs that begin with XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606057/loop-through-all-ids-that-begin-with-xxx))

Then you can get the number at the end of the id like so:

```
var idNum = $(this).attr('id').replace(/myManyDiv/, '');
```

(credit to: [jquery get number from id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427853/jquery-get-number-from-id))

So you end up with (assuming that whatever has already been set):

```
$('[id^=myManyDiv]').each(function() {
    var idNum = $(this).attr('id').replace(/myManyDiv/, '');
    if (whatever === parseInt(idNum)) $(this).addClass('visible');
    else $(this).removeClass('visible');
})
```

For the other two divs, you can worry about them separately:

```
if (whatever < 2) {
    $('#divSome').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone');
}
else {
    $('#divSome').removeClass('displayNone');
    $('#divMany').addClass('displayNone');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The first part is really fantastic. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be using a `function` plus `forloop` inorder to remove `visible` class from all `div`s like the following:

```
function rem_all()
{
    var id ="#myManyDiv";
    for (var i=0;i<11;i++) $(id+i).removeClass('visible');
    $('#divMany').addClass('displayNone');
    $('#divSome').addClass('displayNone');
}
```

then you can change your code like the following:

```
     rem_all();    
    if (whatever == "0") {
        $('#myManyDiv0').addClass('visible');
        $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone');
    } else if (whatever == "1") {
        $('#myManyDiv1').addClass('visible');
        $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone'); //visible div
    } else if (whatever == "2") {
        $('#myManyDiv2').addClass('visible'); //visible div
        $('#divSome').removeClass('displayNone'); //visible div
    }
```

**Edit :**

or better approach for last part:

```
rem_all();
$('#myManyDiv'+whatever).addClass('visible');
if (parseInt(whatever) <2)  $('#divMany').removeClass('displayNone');
else $('#divSome').removeClass('displayNone');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lesion.